# Entity Framework Database First: Foreign Key to Unique Key is not automatically mapped by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Assuming the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [UserId] VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, /*Using GUID IDs for better identification*/ 
    [Email] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    ......
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserLogins]
(
   [Email] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   [Password] VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
   .....
   CONSTRAINT [UserLogins_Users_FK] FOREIGN KEY(Email) REFERENCES [Users](Email) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

When using the EF automatic mapping from database, the `Users` table is not mapped to the `UserLogins` table. Assuming that it is not possible to reverse the unique and primary keys, and I need to do this to save that very little storage area as `VARCHAR(36)` is smaller than `NVARCHAR(50)`, what would be the proper solution to force EF to automatically map these two tables?

Comment: The only way is to tell EF that Users.Email is the primary key.

Comment: @GertArnold: How exactly can I do this when the database is automatically mapped and the table model are automatically generated?

Comment: @GertArnold: And this is not possible since the Users.Email is not a primary key.

Comment: You can modify the primary key indicator in the edmx designer. That will persist if you update the model from the database. If you tell EF i'ts the primary key, EF is happy. And it works becasue it's a natural key (unique).

Comment: @GertArnold: In that case the referential integrity in other tables using the UserId as primary key breaks.

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't visible for me. Then there simply is no way (assuming this is EF6). You have to join the entities if you want to connect them in one query.

Comment: @GertArnold: but you know joins redirect some pressure on the database and they are NOT resource friendly specially in EF and LINQ. I've been advised to avoid joins and specially heavy ones using LINQ and doing them through SQL Views instead.

Comment: Ehh, what? Relational database are specialized for executing joins. And navigation properties also execute joins.

Comment: @GertArnold: Yeah, but when done through EF, and LINQ, they will be way slower than when being implemented using direct SQL code, is that correct?

Comment: @GertArnold: I think in that case, writing a SQL View would be better. (Very low performance difference for this case) but my point is maximizing performance as much as possible. Please correct if I;m wrong though.

Comment: @GertArnold has right! Joins is one of the powerful feature in relational database. 
But I know the problem in EF, if you have a lot of joins in your query which retrieve a lot of data then you will get some  performance issues(slow data loading). those issus maybe coming from missing clustered-Indexes or missing skip-take, etc. There are a lot of tricks to solve perfomrance issues in EF and the problem and if EF struggled and cannot solve the performance  problem then just use a view.

Comment: Could you pls explain what you mean by "automatic mapping" ?

Answer (score -3):

try Use Code First (It has test **successful** on my  local computer):

```
  public class Users
{

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string Emails { get; set; }

    public UserLogins UserLogins { get; set; }
}

public class UserLogins
{
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Users> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UsersMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Users>
{
    public UsersMap()
    {

        this.HasKey(x => x.UserId);
        this.Property(x => x.Emails).HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute() { IsUnique = true }));

        this.HasRequired(x => x.UserLogins).
            WithMany(x => x.Users).HasForeignKey(x => x.Emails);
    }
}

public class UserLoginMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserLogins>
{

    public UserLoginMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(x => x.Email);
    }
}

public class TotalDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TotalDbContext()
        : base("Name=total")
    { 

    }

    public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }

    public DbSet<UserLogins> UserLogins { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder model)
    {
        model.Configurations.Add(new UsersMap());
        model.Configurations.Add(new UserLoginMap());


    }

}
```

then it will create code belows:

```
 public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.UserLogins",
            c => new
                {
                    Email = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Password = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Email);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Users",
            c => new
                {
                    UserId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Emails = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.UserLogins", t => t.Emails, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.Emails, unique: true);

    }
```

it will create tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserLogins] (
[Email] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[Password] [nvarchar](max),
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.UserLogins] PRIMARY KEY ([Email]))


 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
[UserId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
[Emails] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Users] PRIMARY KEY ([UserId]) )


 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_Emails] ON [dbo].[Users]([Emails])
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Users_dbo.UserLogins_Emails] FOREIGN KEY ([Emails]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserLogins] ([Email]) ON DELETE CASCADE
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] (
[MigrationId] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
[ContextKey] [nvarchar](300) NOT NULL,
[Model] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
[ProductVersion] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.__MigrationHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId], [ContextKey]))
```

Comment: The 1:n association is the other way around.